# IOS/Swift: Action method from TextField Generating nil While Unwrapping Optional Error

Tags: ios, swift, option-type

Am just learning Swift so new to optionals and these errors.  I have a textField wired to a VC in Storyboard that was until recently working.  However, something happened so that now when the user taps on the textField the app crashes at runtime with the following error:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

I have removed the outlet property and action method and then recreated them.  I also took all the code out of the action method and it still crashes.

The method subscribes to UITextFieldDelegate:

```
public class myVC : UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource,UITextFieldDelegate {
```

Here are the outletProperty and action methods:

```
 @IBOutlet weak var inputField: UITextField!

    @IBAction func inputFieldTouched(_ sender: Any) {
        //I've emptied it out of any code
    }
```

I've also tried it with and without:

```
self.inputField.delegate = self
```

I have closed and reopened Xcode and also cleaned project.

Can anyone suggest next step to debug this?

Here is the entire trace:

```
libswiftCore.dylib`function signature specialization <preserving fragile attribute, Arg[2] = Dead, Arg[3] = Dead> of Swift._fatalErrorMessage (Swift.StaticString, Swift.StaticString, file : Swift.StaticString, line : Swift.UInt, flags : Swift.UInt32) -> Swift.Never:
    0x100a8c3d0 <+0>:   stp    x26, x25, [sp, #-0x50]!
    0x100a8c3d4 <+4>:   stp    x24, x23, [sp, #0x10]
    0x100a8c3d8 <+8>:   stp    x22, x21, [sp, #0x20]
    0x100a8c3dc <+12>:  stp    x20, x19, [sp, #0x30]
    0x100a8c3e0 <+16>:  stp    x29, x30, [sp, #0x40]
    0x100a8c3e4 <+20>:  add    x29, sp, #0x40            ; =0x40 
    0x100a8c3e8 <+24>:  mov    x19, x6
    0x100a8c3ec <+28>:  mov    x20, x5
    0x100a8c3f0 <+32>:  mov    x21, x4
    0x100a8c3f4 <+36>:  mov    x22, x3
    0x100a8c3f8 <+40>:  mov    x23, x2
    0x100a8c3fc <+44>:  mov    x24, x1
    0x100a8c400 <+48>:  mov    x25, x0
    0x100a8c404 <+52>:  adr    x8, #0xf11fc              ; protocol descriptor for Swift._DefaultCustomPlaygroundQuickLookable + 136
    0x100a8c408 <+56>:  nop    
    0x100a8c40c <+60>:  add    x0, x8, #0x10             ; =0x10 
    0x100a8c410 <+64>:  mov    w1, #0x28
    0x100a8c414 <+68>:  orr    w2, wzr, #0x7
    0x100a8c418 <+72>:  bl     0x100a8c750               ; swift_rt_swift_allocObject
    0x100a8c41c <+76>:  mov    x8, x0
    0x100a8c420 <+80>:  stp    x22, x21, [x8, #0x10]
    0x100a8c424 <+84>:  strb   w20, [x8, #0x20]
    0x100a8c428 <+88>:  str    w19, [x8, #0x24]
    0x100a8c42c <+92>:  adr    x3, #0x40440              ; partial apply forwarder for Swift.(_fatalErrorMessage (Swift.StaticString, Swift.StaticString, file : Swift.StaticString, line : Swift.UInt, flags : Swift.UInt32) -> Swift.Never).(closure #2)
    0x100a8c430 <+96>:  nop    
    0x100a8c434 <+100>: mov    x0, x25
    0x100a8c438 <+104>: mov    x1, x24
    0x100a8c43c <+108>: mov    x2, x23
    0x100a8c440 <+112>: mov    x4, x8
    0x100a8c444 <+116>: bl     0x10096d4dc               ; function signature specialization <preserving fragile attribute, Arg[1] = [Closure Propagated : reabstraction thunk helper from @callee_owned (@unowned Swift.UnsafeBufferPointer<Swift.UInt8>) -> () to @callee_owned (@unowned Swift.UnsafeBufferPointer<Swift.UInt8>) -> (@out ()), Argument Types : [@callee_owned (@unowned Swift.UnsafeBufferPointer<Swift.UInt8>) -> ()]> of generic specialization <preserving fragile attribute, ()> of Swift.StaticString.withUTF8Buffer <A> ((Swift.UnsafeBufferPointer<Swift.UInt8>) -> A) -> A
->  0x100a8c448 <+120>: brk    #0x1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you deleted and recreated the outlets there may be some issues with the outlet connection. Find your connected outlets in the "connections inspector" on the right hand side. You can save-remove the outlets there.

Comment: Hi, I checked them and they looked ok.  The I deleted and recreated the connections in the connection inspector but still same error.

Comment: I tried to recreate your problem with these infos but did not get the "unwrapping optional" error. The only thing that crashed the app was the double outlet connection thing at the textField in the storyboard. I see no issues with your code.